# Where did all the pigeons go?

Tags: tekwar

In the TV movie TekWar: TekLords Jake Cardigan has a conversation with his son Danny in the park, where they throw breadcrumbs on the grass "for the pigeons", as Jake and his grandfather used to do.

Danny asks what a pigeon is, to which Jake replies that he had also asked his grandfather that. Jake explains that a pigeon was a bird, and that when his grandfather was a kid he would throw breadcrumbs and there'd be pigeons as far as the eye could see.

Whether the number of pigeons was an exaggeration or not is unclear, but in either case it would seem that in a relatively short amount of time the cities went from having large flocks of pigeons to having no pigeons. So what happened to them all? Was this explained in the books or the TV series?

Comment: *Long time passing...*

Comment: Apparently pigeons weren't extinct in the novel, the page at http://books.google.com/books?id=rOmft-SDolIC&lpg=PP1&pg=PT120 says "up on the top of the abandoned dome pigeons and doves roosted and their droppings also decorated the walls. Hundreds of birds were fluttering and cooing up there in the darkness now." Maybe the writers of the TV movie just put it in to convey the idea that there had been a lot of environmental destruction, or maybe just to give the audience a sense of the future differing from the present in all sorts of weird unexpected ways.

Comment: @Hypnosifl You should put that together into an answer.

Comment: @Xantec - will do, I was hoping someone who had seen the complete series would have a less speculative answer but I'm guessing they never really explained it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently pigeons weren't extinct in the novel, a page of Tekwar viewable on google books [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=rOmft-SDolIC&lpg=PP1&pg=PT120) says

> ...up on the top of the abandoned dome pigeons and doves roosted and their droppings also decorated the walls. Hundreds of birds were fluttering and cooing up there in the darkness now.

There were a lot of differences between the books and the show though, a big one being that the books were set in 2120 but for the show they used a near-future setting of 2045 (a decision explained [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=KZcIAQAAQBAJ&lpg=PP1&pg=PA329) in terms of budget considerations).

Maybe the writers of the TV movie just put it in to convey the idea that there had been a lot of environmental destruction (also suggested by the radical environmentalist group led by 'WarBride' in the first TV movie--from the Publishers Weekly summary [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0399134956) it sounds like WarBride's cause may have been a civil war rather than anything environmental in the book, but I haven't read it so I'm not sure). Or maybe it was just to give the audience a sense of the future differing from the present in all sorts of weird unexpected ways (kind of like how [owls have replaced pigeons](http://theinfosphere.org/Owls) as the main city bird in the show *Futurama*).